# jquery get value by key WITHOUT looping

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable in jquery as follows:

```
var obj = { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, four: 4, five: 5 };
```

Is there a way to get value by key WITHOUT iteration.

In my original scenario, the variable "obj" contain lots of entries. And will be called frequently. So looping using $.each will cause performance issue.

If there is another way to declare the above variable, then i can do that also. So if anyone have any other method to get value by key WITHOUT looping, then can you please share.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

You can use

```
var obj = { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, four: 4, five: 5 };
console.log(obj.one); // 1
console.log(obj['two']); // 2
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/rrcqr/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Without iteration, then you have to do it directly like

```
obj.one = 1
obj.two = 2
obj.three = 3
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [member operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators)([Dot Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Dot_notation) or [Bracket Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation)) to do it, there is no need for iteration here

`obj.one` will give 1 same as `obj.two` will give 2
Ex:

```
console.log(obj1.one);
console.log(obj1.two);
```

or if the key is stored in a different variable like `var key = 'one'` then `obj[key]` will give 1

```
var key = 'three';
console.log(obj1[key]);
```